# How do I stop a textarea from scrolling to the top whenever I change its value

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea

I'm making something where a textarea gets more and more text appended. In firefox, the textarea scroll back up to the top each time.
I currently have something like `textarea.scrollTop=1000000;` to scroll it back down each time it changes, but it still goes up to the top for a very short time.
Is there any way to stop it doing so?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, too. It happens in IE and Firefox but not Opera and Chrome.

I thought of hiding the momentary jumps to the top by "[double-buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)" changes to the textarea:

1. Create two textareas with the exact same properties and dimensions. Only one of these is visible; the other one is hidden.
2. Append text to the hidden textarea: set [the value of the hidden textarea] to [the value of the visible textarea] + [text to append]. (The textarea will automatically scroll to the top, but this textarea is hidden!)
3. Scroll the hidden textarea to the bottom: set scrollTop to a high integer value like (-1 >>> 1).
4. Swap the hidden textarea with the visible one. Now the new text is shown, sans jumping to top!

You can swap the hidden/visible textareas by using one of two methods:

1. Use absolute positioning to place the textareas on top of each other in conjunction with [toggling their visible property](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Javascript-1520/JavaScript-visibility.htm).
2. Swap the actual DOM elements. I'm not sure if this will introduce a new type of "flicker." You may have to create a div to contain the visible textarea so the layout of the page doesn't keep changing...

Answer (score 0):

i thing that is problem of adding the content via the script, paste your code which append text to your textarea

Comment: the code I use to add to textarea is `textarea.value+=string`

Comment: try to use `textarea.value = textarea.value + string;` , i know that some time ago i had the same problem and i changed the method of adding new content. and it work out but im not sure that this is it.