# How to prevent textarea from scrolling to the top when its value changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll, textarea

Consider the following example: ([Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGJeE/5/))

HTML:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="button">Click Here</div>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
    height: 80px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
}
#button {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var textarea = $("textarea");

    textarea.val("Hello\nStack\nOverflow!\nThere\nAre\nLots\nOf\nGreat\nPeople\nHere");

    $("#button").click(function() {
        textarea.val(textarea.val() + "!");
    });

    textarea.scrollTop(9999).focus(); // Arbitrary big enough number to scroll to the bottom
});
```

When the `#button` is clicked, `textarea` value changes, and for some reason the scroll bar goes to the top (I checked this in Firefox, not sure about other browsers).

Why this is happening ?

How could I fix that ?

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202791/how-do-i-stop-a-textarea-from-scrolling-to-the-top-whenever-i-change-its-value/3302664#3302664) one possible solution, but I wonder if there are other solutions.

Comment: For your information, this does not happen in Chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can save the scrollTop offset, set the value, and reset the scrollTop to the old offset:

```
var $textarea = ...;
var top = $textarea.scrollTop();
$textarea.val('foo');
$textarea.scrollTop(top);
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/QGJeE/7/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution(harder to imply as there is no unique cross-browser-way):

Instead of changing the value of the textarea create a textRange of the textarea's content and modify the ranges text.